# What is the solution for class imbalance in Binary Classification?

Tags: machine-learning

What are the solutions for class imbalance problem?. For example, we have millions of positive examples and hundreds of negative examples. What are all the approaches for building binary classifier?

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/imbalanced-classification-problem/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML methodology.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to handle imbalanced dataset, frequently used are

1. Oversampling
2. Undersampling
3. Hybrid

The [link](http://www.chioka.in/class-imbalance-problem/) might be useful.